# java, Calculating mongodb query execution time

Tags: mongodb, playframework, mongodb-java

I want to log my query times for each time when a query made.

I'm using mongodb on playframework. Simply I'm thinkinig to substract start and end time.For ex:

```
a=currenttime();
madequert();
querytime=currenttime()-a;
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use [Mongo's DB profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler). That way you'll keep that of your code (less work to maintain it) and it will give you more options to check Mongo behaviour.